# How to install Vega plugin for Kibana 5.5.0?

Tags: kibana, kibana-5, vega, vega-lite

I am just starting using Kibana (5.5.0). I found a nice plugin called [Vega](https://github.com/nyurik/kibana-vega-vis). After spending several hours unsuccessfully trying to install this plugin, I decided to publish here this question.
For example, when I run this command `bin/kibana-plugin install file:///ust/test/kibana-vega-vis-master.zip`, I get this error:

```
Attempting to transfer from file:///usr/test/kibana-vega-vis-master.zip
Transferring 25554 bytes....................
Transfer complete
Retrieving metadata from plugin archive
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No kibana plugins found in archive"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are installing the wrong file.  From the [releases page](https://github.com/nyurik/kibana-vega-vis/releases), right click the **vega_vis-5.5.0-(latest version).zip**, use "copy link address", and use that URL with `bin/kibana-plugin install https://...`.

For example, for the current version as of this writing, for Kibana 5.5.0, you would install it with:

```
bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/nyurik/kibana-vega-vis/releases/download/v0.2.3/vega_vis-0.2.3--for-Kibana-5.5.0.zip
```

Comment: but if there no network to use how to install the vega?